# JSON.stringify() not working correctly - Second parameter disappears

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following object:

```
var message = {

    default: 'Default',

    GCM: {

        data: {
            title: titleMessage,
            text: textMessage
        }
    }
};
```

When I realize:

```
message.GCM = JSON.stringify(message.GCM);
```

The variable message.GCM gets the following value:

```
{"data":{"title":"titleMessageValue"}}
```

Instead of:

```
{"data":{"title":"titleMessageValue", "text":"textMessageValue"}}
```

Why does it ignores the second variable from my data object? How can I stringify without lose any variables?

Comment: would happen if textMessage is undefined

Comment: `undefined` and `function` are not valid values for the format **JSON**. See **http://json.org/**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`textMessage` is likely `undefined`.

```
var msg = {
  title: 'titleMessage',
  text: 'textMessage'
};
JSON.stringify(msg); // Both properties are there
msg.text = undefined;
JSON.stringify(msg); // `text` is missing
```

> If undefined, a function, or a symbol is encountered during conversion it is either omitted (when it is found in an object) or censored to null (when it is found in an array).

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Comment: Thanks Mike. In the middle of huge amount of code I've forgot to update the pass the parameter in a piece of code

Comment: @ViníciusMendesdeSouza Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This works ok:

```
var titleMessage = 'This is my title';
var textMessage = 'This is my message';

var message = {
    default: 'Default',
    GCM: {
        data: {
            title: titleMessage,
            text: textMessage
        }
    }
};

message.GCM = JSON.stringify(message.GCM);
```

But note that:

- if `var textMessage = undefined;` it won't appear in the stringify result.
- if `textMessage` does not exist it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Make the JSON like following :

```
var message = {
    default: 'Default',
    GCM: {
         data: {
         title: 'titleMessage',
         text: 'textMessage'
       } 
    }
 };
```

Or define the two variables titleMessage and textMessage